# Serialization Circular exception caused by self-referencing Read-only property

Tags: .net, serialization, datacontract, circular-reference

When trying to return an object from a JSON asp.net 3.5SP1 WebService (not WCF, classic asp.net WebService with *scriptservice* attribute), I have an **"A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'Geo.Bound'"** error, caused by a self-referencing Read-only property :

Simplified Code :

```
Namespace Geo
<DataContract(Namespace:="Geo", IsReference:=True)> _
Public Class Bound

 <DataMember(Name:="sw", IsRequired:=False)> _
 Public SouthWestCoord As Double


 Public Sub New()
  SouthWestCoord = 1.5#
 End Sub

 <IgnoreDataMember()> _
 Public ReadOnly Property Bds() As Bound
  Get
   Return Me
  End Get
 End Property

End Class
End Namespace
```

- I want to keep the Read-Only property because it's used for implementing an interface.
- Adding a "IsReference:=True" attribute to Bound class changes nothing.
- If I use a DataContractJsonSerializer (outside the context of webservice, like this exemple : [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28VS.95%29.aspx)), it works and I have a correct JSON.
- If I remove the "Bds" Read-only property it works !!

I don't understand why ! It's a readonly property, without a DataMember attribute, with a IgnoreDatamember attribute, it's not supposed to be serialized !

How to keep the "Bds" property, and get rid of the circular reference exception ?

Thanks !

Comment: How did you set up WCF to work with DataContractJsonSerializer? Maybe you made a mistake there?

Comment: My question was not clear, so I Edited it : it's a classic asp.net service (not WCF), the test with DataContractJsonSerializer was outside the context of a webservice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is example, that works (sorry for C#)

1. Defined class:

   ```
   [DataContract(Namespace = "Geo")]
   public class Bound
   {
       [IgnoreDataMember]
       public Bound { get { return this; } }


      [DataMember]
      public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Created Service Interface (and implementation)

   ```
   [ServiceContract]
   public interface IService1
   {
       [OperationContract]
       [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
       Bound DoWork();
   }


   public class Service1 : IService1
   {
       public Bound DoWork()
       {
           return new Bound { Name = "Test Name" };
       }
   }
   ```
3. Edited system.serviceModel part of app.config

   ```
   <behaviors>
     <endpointBehaviors>
       <behavior name="endBeh">
         <enableWebScript/>
       </behavior>
     </endpointBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
   <services>
     <service name="JsonSerializationTest.Service1">
       <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="endBeh" contract="JsonSerializationTest.IService1" />
       <host>
         <baseAddresses>
           <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/JsonSerializationTest/Service1/"/>
         </baseAddresses>
       </host>
     </service>
   </services>
   ```
4. Started Service Host in Program.cs

   ```
   using (var sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1)))
   {
       sh.Open();
       Console.WriteLine("Opened");
       Console.ReadLine();
   }
   ```

Started program, opened browser, typed http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/JsonSerializationTest/Service1/DoWork and recieved Json-ed test object:

```
{"d":{"__type":"Bound:Geo","Name":"Test Name"}}
```

PS: WebInvokeAttribute is located in *System.ServiceModel.Web.dll* assembly.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use WCF in this project, but knowing that it works in WCF is intersting...

Comment: Oh, sorry. Good luck with classic ASP.NET. )

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the circular reference Because it's the class Bound with a reference to a property of type Bound. That means it's an **endless** supply of Bound objects.

Not sure on why IgnoreDataMember isn't working right. I will give this some more time and update my answer if I have any ideas.